# zoom api: I can create, list, delete, etc a meeting. But I can't get the video from the api

Tags: javascript, zoom-sdk

I want to get the video open from my js app. I can do create, list, delete, etc a meeting. But I can't get the video using api. Is there a way to get the video also using zoom api?

Comment: Hi there no there is no way to get video using API.. zoom does not provide web RTC clients.. but they do provide video join directly via browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Zoom Video Meetings in your JavaScript application with the [Zoom Web SDK](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/web).

[Here is a related thread](https://devforum.zoom.us/t/how-to-get-image-data-from-recipient-video-canvas/6101) on getting the actual Video Stream of a Zoom Meeting using the Web SDK.